# No class found execption in android blogger share

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, blogger

No Class found exception in android blogger share.

```
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966): Process: com.ocs.socialshare.bloggershare, PID: 5966
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaThumbnail
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.google.gdata.data.blogger.PostEntry.declareExtensions(PostEntry.java:57)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile.addDeclarations(ExtensionProfile.java:71)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.declareExtensions(BaseFeed.java:235)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.google.gdata.client.blogger.BloggerService.declareExtensions(BloggerService.java:145)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.google.gdata.client.blogger.BloggerService.<init>(BloggerService.java:84)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.ocs.socialshare.bloggershare.BloggerClient.oAuthBlogger(BloggerClient.java:409)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.ocs.socialshare.bloggershare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-10 07:11:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(5966):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this errror is commonly caused by missing library, have you imported in your project this:

```
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaThumbnail;
```

?

if not first import in your android project library by download it first:

download-link: 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-src.java-1.47.1.zip&can=1&q=gdata

Comment: thanks finally i got jar from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgdata1300jar.htm

Comment: you're welcome ! good work :)